# java script and html

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a project that shows the current temp and humidity on a webpage using server send events. Luckily, all the code works fine but the main problem is I can't write the syntax that shows the current temp from the updating function.

My main purpose is to get the value from the updating function as text.

For example, the updating function is `Updatething.temp()' can any one give me an example to get the text value from it and show it as text using JavaScript, jQuery and HTML ?!!

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to provide us with some of the code you are working with. This is very vague and all we can assume is that you will be returning a value from that function.

Comment: Please add the code you have written for 'Updatething.temp()'

Comment: Side note: @SH_ avoid editing if you can't make post completely on-topic. If OP does not provide [MCVE] your effort is completely lost. Also please check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you as you kept "thank you" notice in the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - are you saying that if I edit spelling and grammar (enabling the community a clearer interpretation for an answer) then my effort is completely lost ? I left the 'thanks' in because it seemed harmless and human which is what separates us from the machines but noted. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @SH_ mainly because if question not improved to meet SO quality bar it will likely get removed along with your edits. Since it requires 3-5 other people to review such changes it eats a lot of effort for something that will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a div on your html-

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

In your javascript, get the temp value from the function, and inject it to the div:

```
var myValue = Updatething.temp(); //get the value
$('#myDiv').innerHTML = myValue;  //select your div, and change it's inner html to the temp
```

The resulting div will be this (assuming temp is 42 for example):

```
<div id='myDiv'>42</div>
```